# Write Data From List To CSV File

Tags: unity

I am trying to write to a CSV file the values that I put in lists from a key press in the keyboard. It does work somehow but in my csv file I get the values 2 times. Also, when I put values to only one of the lists, I don't get any data to CSV file. How can I save the values from the lists to my csv file but to be independent from each other? This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class record : MonoBehaviour
{

public List<string> inventory = new List<string>();
public List<string> OnlyX = new List<string>();

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        inventory.Add("F");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
    {
        inventory.Add("J");
    } 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        OnlyX.Add("X");
    }
    string filePath = getPath();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
    writer.WriteLine("Inventory,OnlyX");

    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < OnlyX.Count; ++j) {

            writer.WriteLine(inventory[i] + "," + OnlyX[j]);
        } 
    }
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
private string getPath()
{
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
    return Application.dataPath + "/Data/"  + "Saved_Inventory.csv";
 #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    return Application.persistentDataPath+"Saved_Inventory.csv";
 #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    return Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+"Saved_Inventory.csv";
 #else
    return Application.dataPath +"/"+"Saved_Inventory.csv";
 #endif
}
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to open a file (and do any IO tbh) in the main thread

Comment: But how can I change that? I have the main code in Update function, so it's best to open the Excel file in the Update function as well. Is there any other way? I have asked the same question here as well and maybe I explain it better with the comments: https://forum.unity.com/threads/write-data-from-list-to-csv-file.643561/#post-4313491 @Bálint

Comment: You're adding every item in your list to your file every frame. Did you mean to write just the newest entry into your file when it's added to the list?

Comment: So if I first add to inventory list F => this should be saved to csv file to first row to first column named Inventory, then if I add again F =? the data should be saved again to Inventory column to second row. Then if I add X, this value should be saved to column OnlyX to first row. So basically I would save my values the same way they are saved in list. I think this means what you said, to write the value when it is added to the list @DMGregory